# if $a_{n+1}=xa_{n}+ya_{n-1}$ find the $a,b,x,y$ such $(a_{m},a_{n})=a_{(m,n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

it is well  known:
if $F_{1}=1,F_{2}=1$,and $F_{n+1}=F_{n}+F_{n-1}$.use
$$F_{m+n}=F_{m}F_{n+1}+F_{m-1}F_{n}$$
I can  prove $(F_{m},F_{n})=F_{(m,n)}$

also I have  solve this following problem
$a_{1}=a_{2}=1$,and $p,q$ be postive integer,and such $a_{n+2}=pa_{n+1}+qa_{n}$
if $$p=1\Longleftrightarrow (a_{m},a_{n})=a_{(m,n)}$$
proof:since
$$a_{3}=p+q,a_{4}=p^2+pq+q,a_{5}=p^3+p^2q+2pq+q^2,a_{6}=p^4+p^3q+3p^2q+2pq^2+q^2$$
if $(a_{m},a_{n})=a_{(m,n)}$ so
$$1=a_{(3,4)}=(a_{3},a_{4})=(p+q,p^2+pq+q)\Longrightarrow (p,q)=1$$
and note
$a_{3}=(a_{3},a_{6})\Longrightarrow a_{3}|a_{6}$，so
$$(p+q)|(p^2q+q^2)=q(p+q)+pq(p-1)$$
so $p=1$

and other hand we if $p=1$,use [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979611/if-a-n1-xa-nya-n-1-then-have-this-results-a-mn-xa-ma-n1ya)  we have
$$a_{m+n}=a_{m+1}a_{n}+qa_{m}a_{n-1}$$
and it is easy to show
$(a_{n+2},a_{n+1})=(qa_{n},a_{n+1})=(a_{n},a_{n+1})$ because $(a_{n+2},q)=(a_{n+1},q)=\cdots=(1,q)=1$
so we have$(a_{n+1},a_{n})=1$, then
$$(a_{m+n},a_{n})=(a_{m}a_{n+1}+qa_{m-1}a_{n},a_{n})=(a_{m},a_{n})=\cdots=(a_{(m,n)},a_{(m,n)})=a_{(m,n)}$$
then we have
$$(a_{m},a_{n})=a_{(m,n)}$$

> My question: let $a,b,x,y$ be postive integers,and sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such $a_{1}=a,a_{2}=b$,and
> $$a_{n+1}=xa_{n}+ya_{n-1}$$
> find the $a,b,x,y$ such $(a_{m},a_{n})=a_{(m,n)}$

Comment: Related topics are studied in https://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL20/He/he59.pdf See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145404/the-gcd-operator-commutes-with-functions-defined-by-linear-recurrence-relatio

Comment: @GerryMyerson,Hello,I read this paper,and   I don't see the end result of this problem

Comment: @gero I didn't say the result was there; I said the paper studied topics related to the problem. In particular, there is a remark in the paper which relates divisibility sequences to sequences with the gcd property. It is often useful, when studying a problem, to learn about related problems.

Comment: Conjecture: The property holds iff $b = ax$ and $(y,x) = 1$. Those are necessary properties by looking at the first fourth terms, and I haven't found a counterexample in the first terms of the first sequences.

Comment: Have you looked at the links I gave, function?

Comment: It's not polite to ignore people who are trying to help you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,I have find a paper disscuss this question.Thanks.see  P.HORAK and L.SKULA 1983 A characterization of the second-order strong divisibility sequences:https://www.mscs.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/23-2/horak.pdf

Comment: Good. If that enables you to solve the problem, let me encourage you to write up the solution and post it here as an answer, so that we have it on file for the next person who comes along with this question.

Comment: You could do that today.